# Chain rule on multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice continuously differentiable functions. I want to compute
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g(f)}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y).    
$$

If I apply the chain rule twice,
$$
\frac{\partial g(f)}{\partial y}(x,y) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial f}(f(x,y))\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) \qquad (1)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g(f)}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial f^{2}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x\partial y}. 
\qquad (2)
$$

Is this correct? Intuitively, I think only the second term should remain, because $x$ and $y$ affects $f$ and then $f$ affects $g$.

Comment: It turns out that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Big[g\left(f(x,y)\right)\Big]=g'\left(f(x,y)\right)f_{y}(x,y)$. Can you finish?

Comment: @MatthewH. That is what I wrote in Eq. (1). And then I applied the product rule and the chain rule to get (2). But, I am struggling to interpret the first term in (1).

Comment: One caveat, in Eq. (1) you wrote $g^{'}(f(x,y))$ with the partial derivative notation. That differs from what @MatthewH. wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close but not quite.  The correct expressions should be
$$\frac{\partial g(f)}{\partial y} = \frac{\color{red}{d}g}{\color{red}{d}f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \tag{1}$$ and
$$\frac{\partial^2 g(f)}{\partial x \, \partial y}=\frac{\color{red}{d}^2g}{\color{red}{d} f^{2}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\color{red}{d}g}{\color{red}{df}}\frac{\partial^{\color{red}{2}} f}{\partial x \,\partial y} \tag{2}$$ where I have noted the errors in red.  Note we prefer to use $d$ instead of $\partial$ when writing the derivative of $g$ with respect to $f$, since $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a univariate function, although writing $\partial$ is not strictly disallowed.  The superscript $2$ in the second-order partial derivative $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \, \partial y}$ is required otherwise the notation is not consistent.  However, the critical error is writing $\partial g/\partial x$ rather than $dg/df$.  The other issues might be dismissed as oversights, but this one is a major problem.

If you have any doubts, you can of course pick some simple but nontrivial functions; e.g.,
$$f(x,y) = x^2 y + y^3, \quad g(f) = \sin f.$$  Then we have
$$g(f(x,y)) = \sin (x^2 y + y^3)$$ and $$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2xy, \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= x^2 + 3y^2, \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \, \partial y} &= 2x, \\
\frac{d g}{d f} &= \cos f, \\
\frac{d^2 g}{df^2} &= -\sin f.
\end{align}$$
Then we have
$$\frac{\partial g(f(x,y))}{\partial y} = \frac{dg}{df} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = (\cos f)(x^2 + 3y^2) = (x^2 + 3y^2) \cos (x^2 y + y^3)$$ by the formula you obtained, and
$$\frac{\partial g(f(x,y))}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[\sin (x^2 y + y^3)\right] = \cos (x^2 y + y^3) \cdot (x^2 + 3y^2)$$ by direct application of partial differentiation to the explicit composition.

Similarly, the mixed partial derivative is via the formula $(2)$
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 g(f(x,y))}{\partial x \, \partial y} &= (-\sin f)(2xy)(x^2 + 3y^2) + (\cos f)(2x) \\
&= -2xy(x^2+3y^2) \sin (x^2y + y^3) + 2x \cos (x^2 y + y^3),
\end{align}$$
and by differentiating the composition,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 g(f(x,y))}{\partial x \, \partial y}
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ \sin (x^2 y + y^3) \right] \right] \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ (x^2 + 3y^2) \cos (x^2 y + y^3) \right] \\
&= (x^2 + 3y^2) (-\sin (x^2 y + y^3) \cdot 2xy) + (2x) \cos (x^2 y + y^3) \\
&= -2xy(x^2 + 3y^2) \sin (x^2 y + y^3) + 2x \cos (x^2 y + y^3).
\end{align}$$